# User text box input is rewritten by default value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Consider the following `.aspx` page:

```
        Title: 
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TitleTB"></asp:TextBox> 
        Details:
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DetailsTB"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn" Text="Submit" OnClick="Btn_click"/>
```

Note that I minimized the code to be legitimate so a lot of lines are missing (irrelevant lines, `<br/>` for example).

In the C# file, I usually post the details to the database (inserting them), but if I have a certain field in my query string (`to_edit`, per se) I need to update the, already existing, record.

Obviously, this task is overall simple. The thing is, that when that field is included, I initially (in the `Page_Load` event) set the `Title` and the `Details` fields to the values already found in the record (so the user won't have to input from zero, he'd have the ones he already entered to edit).

A debug would show, though, that when I post these back to the database (`UPDATE` query, which looks a bit like this `UPDATE Table SET Title = @Title, Details = @Details WHERE ID=@ID`, where I checked `@ID` - which is completely valid. `@Title` corresponds to `TitleTB.Text` and `@Details` to `DetailsTB.Text`, both added with `SqlCommand.AddWithValue()`) that `DetailsTB.Text` and `TitleTB.Text` are, for some reason, the same as I assigned them in the `Page_Load` although I deleted the whole text box content in my browser and refilled it with a different string.

Here are chosen parts of my Code Behind:

```
//A part of my Page_Load()
//reader is an SqlDataReader, the connection is valid, the values here are valid, and the output is as planned.
TitleTB.Text = (string)reader["Title"];
DetailsTB.Text = (string)reader["Details"];
```

And up to now, everything seems fine.

```
//Relevant parts of Btn_click()
        cmd.Connection = conn; //valid connection
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE QuestionsTable SET Title = @Title, Details = @Details WHERE ID=@ID";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TitleTB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", DetailsTB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString["to_edit"]);

        conn.Open();
        int affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //affected is now 1, as expected.
        conn.Close();
        //There's a redirection over here.
```

But in the code shown above, `TitleTB.Text` and `DetailsTB.Text` are the same, it's not that the update query doesn't work. It's that, for some reason, the text boxes values won't change even when I clearly change them on my browser.

Any idea what could happen?

EDIT:

One remark is that when I use the `OnClientClick` event to alert the values (and then returning true, it was only for a test) - the values are identical to what I typed (not to the default value).

Comment: Have you handled `PostBack` in your `Page_Load` event?

Comment: Can you check from your database table, which value is being updated? The default one or the one you are entering?

Comment: @ChandanRoy I did handle `PostBack`. The database table is updated to the default value (which is the same as not being updated) but it is updated.

Comment: Try wrapping your `Page_Load` event code in `If(!IsPostBack){ }`. My guess is, the postback property of the button is refreshing the page with default value.

Comment: @ChandanRoy That was the problem! Thank you a lot. Post it as an answer so I can rate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Page_Load event code in `If(!IsPostBack){ }`. The postback property of the button is refreshing the page with default value.

The code should be as follows -

```
If(!IsPostBack) {

//A part of my Page_Load()
//reader is an SqlDataReader, the connection is valid, the values here are valid, and the output is as planned.
TitleTB.Text = (string)reader["Title"];
DetailsTB.Text = (string)reader["Details"];

}
```

A good read may be helpful - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811684/Understanding-The-Complete-Story-of-Postback-in-AS

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons for such behavior is that you forgot to check if `Page_Load` is caused by a post back and you overwrite text both values in both get and post.

Just try to add an obvious condition:

```
//A part of my Page_Load()
//reader is an SqlDataReader, the connection is valid, the values here 

if ( !this.IsPostback ) 
{
   TitleTB.Text = (string)reader["Title"];
   DetailsTB.Text = (string)reader["Details"];
}
```

Note that control values are stored in the viewstate and thus there is no need to update them during consecutive post backs.

Comment: Your answer is the most constructive and helpful currently, I rated the other question only because he did comment it earlier.

Comment: No problem, I haven't read comments below the question but indeed, it seems the correct comment was made earlier than my response.